# Compare table data and print as per condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
ID int(11) NO PRI NULL 
NAME varchar(20) NO NULL 
SALARY decimal(18,2) YES NULL
```

here, I want to print all the names where the salary of a person is less than another person.

for eg

```
15 adam 1500
16 bob 2000
17 marley 5000
```

will show the result:

```
adam bob
adam Marley
bob Marley
```

I am able to run the double for loops in the MySQL, however, it is failing because it is not getting the name with lower salary on the left side.

Here is my attempt:

```
select
        t1.name, " ", 
        t2.name 
    from
        table t1 
    join
        table t2 
    where
        t1.Salary >  t2.Salary;
```

can someone suggest what may be wrong here?

Comment: Find an example of a query with `" ",` in it. Then get back to us

Comment: Ha ha, well I just got one above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't show the name with lower salary on the left side is because you're using the wrong comparison operator. Try using `<` instead.

**Query:**

```
SELECT t1.name AS lower, t2.name AS higher
FROM `T` AS t1 
JOIN `T` AS t2 
WHERE t1.salary < t2.salary;
```

Check out a live demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/216dd/6).

---

**Note:**

Also, note that using `" "` in a query doesn't make sense. If what you're trying to do is concatenate the names, then you can supplant the above `SELECT` clause with the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.name, " ", t2.name) AS name
```

You can find more about `CONCAT` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: Awesome . Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome @CodeMonkey! I'm glad I could help 